# Py2app ignoring local packages

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, py2app

I currently have the following setup.py: https://github.com/Pext/Pext/blob/30384647024ad3474d2c955d642ad6f7f745ffb5/setup.py

I am trying to build a .app of this, but I py2app seems to ignore the listed packages. Noticeably incorrect is the following output when running `python3 setup.py py2app` (and running the app crashing it due to missing these imports):

```
Modules not found (unconditional imports):

[...]

 * pext_base (/Users/travis/build/Pext/Pext/pext/__main__.py, __main__)

 * pext_helpers (/Users/travis/build/Pext/Pext/pext/__main__.py, __main__)
```

However, pext_base.py and pext_helpers.py are in pext/helpers, as defined in https://github.com/Pext/Pext/blob/30384647024ad3474d2c955d642ad6f7f745ffb5/setup.py#L54.

I've spent many, many hours trying to figure this one out. I have tried the following (and more):
- Stating the packages again in the py2app options dict
- Renaming pext/helpers to pext.helpers in setup.py
- Passing command line --packages=pext,pext/helpers,pext_dev (which makes py2app complain there is no package named pext)
- Using includes instead of packages
- Adding **init**.py files to all package roots and using setuptools.find_packages()
- More things I forgot

I just cannot seem to get py2app to behave, only an aliased build (-A) works.

Does anyone have a clue why this isn't working and what I can do to make it work? Any help would be very much appreciated.